# ValueError: conflicting sizes for dimension 'lat': length 1626 on 'lat' and length 1 on {'lat': 'doc', 'lon': 'doc'}

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a problem with this code.

```py
df = pd.read_excel("./data/example.xlsx", keep_default_na=False)

col_mission = df['mission'].tolist()
col_jour = df['jour'].tolist()
col_heure = df['heure'].tolist()
col_lat = df['lat'].tolist()
col_lon = df['lon'].tolist()
col_doc = df['doc'].tolist()

col_mission = [x for x in col_mission if x != '']
col_jour = [x for x in col_jour if x != '']
col_heure = [x for x in col_heure if x != '']
col_lat = [x for x in col_lat if x != '']
col_lon = [x for x in col_lon if x != '']
col_doc = [x for x in col_doc if x != '']
   

df = xr.Dataset(
    coords={'lat': (col_lat), 'lon': (col_lon)},
    data_vars= {'doc': (('lat', 'lon'), [col_doc])}
        
)
```

I try to create a netcdf file with xarray but the problem I have always comes back. I can't get doc with two parameters: `lat` and `lon`.

All `col_lon`, `col_lat`, `col_doc` lists are 1-dimensional and contain values such as:
`[151.017, 151.017, 136.733, 136.733, 181.966, 181.966, 123.794, 123.794, 122.631, 122.631, 121.755, 121.755, 113.43, 113.43]`.

Comment: Can you make this reproducible? I cannot understand the problem from the code given. Explain what col_doc etc. are in the question

Comment: col_doc is a list of data that is a function of longitude and latitude

Comment: As I said, you’ll need to make the problem reproducible. Amend the code and question or you aren’t likely to get an answer

Comment: I edit my question and I put my program

Comment: I'm not sure why you are doing it this way. There is a `to_xarray` method available for converting dataframes to xarray datasets

Comment: yes it exists but the problem is that I need to work on the variables and I don't think I can do it with to_xarray